# How can I migrate PostgreSQL database to the Elastic index?

Tags: java, postgresql, elasticsearch

I have a project which uses PostgreSQL, and Elastic for fast search. Can I make the database data go to the Elastic index, but not all columns? How can I automate this process with every change in the database?

I tried to do this manually, but there are some update functions so it is almost impossible to do manually.

Comment: Write the client to save to Elasticsearch when you save to PostgreSQL, so that there are two save/update/delete functions one for postgre, other for elasticsearch. Else we can also use JDBC drivers to migrate which may not be realtime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the Logstash JDBC plugin to run a query on your Postgresql database, and feed that data into Elasticsearch.

More information about Logstash JDBC input plugin can be found documented here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6153689/ben-m-ward     Hi thanks a lot but look I have properties table , property units table which has property id in it so i'd like to filter it like to have an index and then send like 1 id having property row in the index and then all units which have property id 1 and then do the same with 2 id then 3 id and so on is that possible i wanna do this for further search?

Comment: Using the JDBC plugin, the "statement" field of the jdbc input driver can be any valid psql query command. You could run a query on your property id, and then use Kibana or another elastic implementation of your choosing to edit the filters of the index for a given property id.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6153689/ben-m-ward.  thanks a lot it worked )

Comment: @GrigorMartiros Fantastic I'm glad to hear, please mark the above as an accepted answer so others can benefit!

Comment: it says you need 15 reputations